# Is using custom json content-types a good idea

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm designing a RESTful API and in an attempt to be descriptive and make documentation clearer I want to declare my content-type http header as follows:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.mycorp.mydatatype+json
```

where mycorp is an identifier unique to my corporation and mydatatype is unique to each data type. An example would be:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ford.car+json

{
"manufactured_year": 2000
, "color": "blue"
, "hp": 160
, "model" "Focus"
, "type": "sedan"
}
```

This content-type would be required in order for a POST to be valid and would be sent as a part of a response. It seems to me like a nice way to define rules for what should be inside the payload.

I can't seem to find a good resource on whether this is a good idea or if it is even allowed by IETF standards.

So, question is: Which is more feasible, application/vnd.mycorp.mydatatype+json or just application/json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's allowed, definitely. Whether it's a good idea is another story.

My rule of thumb is that it's a primary data format that's useful across a lot of things, needs to be identified on its own, and you need to interoperate across many applications, definitely give it a media type.

However, if it's just a message in your API among many, and it's only good for one resource (or one resource "type"), just use application/json.

YMMV, of course.

Comment: That's a good point. The big question is of course what is a "primary datatype" and what isn't. I have a datatype that's well defined by my documentation ... but that's always the case with RPC APIs and I rarely find people using this method to denote their datatypes. I wonder if that's because this is not a good way to do it or because API implementors just usually don't think about this.

Answer (score 20):

The question is strongly related to your REST API **versioning**.

Content type is used to, well, define the type of the content. 
If you use a *standard* content type like

```
application/json
```

you're saying to the client that the message is in JSON format. This is enough for all the web applications which do not version their API or support only the latest version.
If you are going to have clients using different versions of your API, *standard* content types are not enough.
Consider the following scenario:

Take your example as version 1 of the message

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ford.carV1+json

{
"manufactured_year": 2000
, "color": "blue"
, "hp": 160
, "model" "Focus"
, "type": "sedan"
}
```

At some point you decide you want represent the color using hexadecimal code. Therefore you create version 2 of the type

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ford.carV2+json

{
"manufactured_year": 2000
, "color": "0000FF"
, "hp": 160
, "model" "Focus"
, "type": "sedan"
}
```

When the client asks for a car specifies the correct content type, which includes the version. This tells the application whether send the color as hex code or as name.

Here you are versioning the **representation** of a resource. An alternative to support resource representation versioning is adding the version as custom header (while keeping content-type standard)

```
Content-Type: application/json
Message-Version: 1.0
```