# Overload Controller Method in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller that needs to behave differently with different URL parameters. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public A getA(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String query) {
    ...
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public A getA(@RequestParam int id) {
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map '[controller name]' bean method
```

Is there a way that the application chooses the method depending on the URL params?

Comment: Explain _doesn't seem to work_. What do you expect it to do? Why do you have those expectations? How does it actually behave?

Comment: Thank you for the questions, I extended my post.

Comment: Just use one method, and set the `@RequestParam` `required` to `false`.

Comment: that's not really what i wanted to do: in fact i have more than 2 params and that would result in very many ifs and elses when i use only one method. moreover it does not seem very java-esk to force very different behavior into one method.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that controller's `@RequestMapping` methods' names don't really matter at all.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Indicate in the mapping which params should be present

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"id", "query"})
public A getA(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String query) {
    ...
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"id"})
public A getA(@RequestParam int id) {
    ...
}
```

Since Spring MVC version 4.3, the new `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, and similar annotations also have this `params` element you can use

```
@GetMapping(params = {"id"})
public A getA(@RequestParam int id) {
    ...
}
```