# How to make multiple @PatchMapping in a single controller?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm new at Spring and REST API themselves, and I would like to make a PatchMapper for multiple properties of my Entity "Employee" in a single controller but I get this error:

"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'employeeController' method 
public resttest.testexercise.model.Employee resttest.testexercise.controller.EmployeeController.patchLN(java.util.Map,java.lang.Integer)
to {PATCH /api/employees/{id}}: There is already 'employeeController' bean method"

I couldn't think of a way to Patch Map multiple properties within a single Entity Controller, and I've only seen answers to Patch Map single property. Is there a way to do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package resttest.testexercise.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import resttest.testexercise.exception.EmployeeNotFoundException;
import resttest.testexercise.exception.EmployeeUnSupportedFieldPatchException;
import resttest.testexercise.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import resttest.testexercise.model.Employee;
import resttest.testexercise.repository.EmployeeRepository;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PatchMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public Employee patchFN(@RequestBody Map<String, String> update, @PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {

        return employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .map(x -> {

                    String first_name = update.get("first_name");
                    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(first_name)) {
                        x.setFirst_name(first_name);

                        return employeeRepository.save(x);
                    } else {
                        throw new EmployeeUnSupportedFieldPatchException(update.keySet());
                    }

                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
                });

    }

    @PatchMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public Employee patchLN(@RequestBody Map<String, String> update, @PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {

        return employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .map(x -> {

                    String last_name = update.get("last_name");
                    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(last_name)) {
                        x.setLast_name(last_name);

                        return employeeRepository.save(x);
                    } else {
                        throw new EmployeeUnSupportedFieldPatchException(update.keySet());
                    }

                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
                });

    }

    @PatchMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public Employee patchBDay(@RequestBody Map<String, String> update, @PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {

        return employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .map(x -> {

                    String birthday = update.get("birthday");
                    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(birthday)) {
                        x.setBirthday(birthday);

                        return employeeRepository.save(x);
                    } else {
                        throw new EmployeeUnSupportedFieldPatchException(update.keySet());
                    }

                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
                });

    }

    @PatchMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public Employee patchAdd(@RequestBody Map<String, String> update, @PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {

        return employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .map(x -> {

                    String address = update.get("address");
                    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(address)) {
                        x.setAddress(address);

                        return employeeRepository.save(x);
                    } else {
                        throw new EmployeeUnSupportedFieldPatchException(update.keySet());
                    }

                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
                });

    }

    @PatchMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public Employee patchPos(@RequestBody Map<String, String> update, @PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {

        return employeeRepository.findById(id)
                .map(x -> {

                    String position = update.get("position");
                    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(position)) {
                        x.setPosition(position);

                        return employeeRepository.save(x);
                    } else {
                        throw new EmployeeUnSupportedFieldPatchException(update.keySet());
                    }

                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
                });

    }


}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'employeeController' method 
public resttest.testexercise.model.Employee resttest.testexercise.controller.EmployeeController.patchLN(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.lang.Integer)
to {PATCH /api/employees/{id}}: There is already 'employeeController' bean method
public resttest.testexercise.model.Employee resttest.testexercise.controller.EmployeeController.patchFN(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.lang.Integer) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at resttest.testexercise.TestexerciseApplication.main(TestexerciseApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'employeeController' method 
public resttest.testexercise.model.Employee resttest.testexercise.controller.EmployeeController.patchLN(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.lang.Integer)
to {PATCH /api/employees/{id}}: There is already 'employeeController' bean method
public resttest.testexercise.model.Employee resttest.testexercise.controller.EmployeeController.patchFN(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.lang.Integer) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:618) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:586) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:312) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$1(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:282) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:280) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:252) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:211) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:199) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:164) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I doesn't mean having two identical endpoint. You can have multiple patch mapping but with different path's

Comment: Should I change the parameter of @PatchMapping, or the PathVariable?

Comment: Just the path parameter in @PatchMapping

Comment: But if I change that wouldn't my paths per ID be informal and inconsistent?

EDIT: It worked. Thank you! I also realized it would be more formal to have certain paths when editing single properties for the entity.

Comment: I you want to have resource management, yes. But it's not a bad practice to have multiple endpoint in a controller. It depends to your requirement. I think you need to redesign the endpoints. In your case You don't need multiple patch. Just check which parameters are available in `update` and take them.

Comment: @Viciou, why do you need same endpoint for multipletime?  you can do do all update via `patchoperation` in a single `endpoint`. Your `endpoint` should vary based on the operation type only

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do. You can only [overload methods in Spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380498/overload-controller-method-in-java-spring) which have the identical mappings for the identical path though this is highly discouraged.

In practice, you shouldn't use more than once any type of HTTP verb for every distinct path.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a "visitor pattern". This solution requiers one PATCH methode with an abstract resource in parameter.

```
@PatchMapping(value = "/foo/{id}", consumes = "application/json")
@Secured("MY_ROLE")
public void patch(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody @Valid Resource patch) {
    //in a service you can do that
    patch.accept(new StateVisitor() {
        @Override
        public void visit(Foo resource) {
           //do job ...
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Bar resource) {
           //do job....
        }
       //...
    });
}
```

}

for example

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo extends Resource {

@NotNull
private ArchiveState archiveState;


@Override
public void accept(StateVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
   }
}
```

The abstract class

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "fooKey"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar.class, name = "barKey")
})
public abstract class Resource implements Visitable<StateVisitor> {

}
```

The interface visitable

```
public interface Visitable<T> {

void accept(T visitor);
}
```

The StateVisitor

```
public interface StateVisitor {

void visit(Foo resource);

void visit(Bar resource);

 }
```

In your json juste indicate the key to helps jackson to map the right class. And this is makes the trick :)

Hope it's help :)