# How to handle Multiple inherited DTOs in a single controller / service method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, design-patterns, dto

I have got PaymentTransactionDTO as superclass and subclasses like PhoneBillPaymentTransactionDTO which has a field as phoneNumber etc.

and I would like to handle these DTOs from single payment service. My controller method like below;

```
public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> payment(@PathVariable String accountNumber,
        @Valid @RequestBody PaymentTransactionDTO paymentTransactionDTO)
```

When I post PhoneBillPaymentTransactionDTO to the method above, I can't reach phoneNumber field as I have PaymentTransactionDTO in the method signature.

How should I have a design to manage multiple inherited dtos from single method ?

Answer (score 1):

**If using Jackson**, you could achieve that with [@JsonTypeInfo/@JsonSubTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17247382/9138818) on the parent class, but a cast would still be needed to reach phoneNumber.

**To avoid any class cast**, you'll need to [overload your controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381348/9138818) with as many signatures as needed (one per child class of PaymentTransactionDTO at least), and with an explicit JSON structure requirement

```
// should handle requests containing a phoneNumber attribute
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"phoneNumber"}) 
public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> payment(@PathVariable String accountNumber,
        @Valid @RequestBody PhoneBillPaymentTransactionDTO phoneBillPaymentTransactionDTO) { 
    // code handling specially phone
}

// should handle any request not containing other specified attributes
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> payment(@PathVariable String accountNumber,
        @Valid @RequestBody PaymentTransactionDTO paymentTransactionDTO) { 
    // code handling the generic transaction
}
```

Under you can still, from the 'phone' related code, call the base transaction controller method, or also split your controller/service into specific code relying on base implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I solved it by using Jackson.