# Spring Boot - How to remove RequestMapping from inherited method

Tags: java, spring

I have very standard APIs so I've created a generic controller to do the mapping (*Controllers* are used only for mapping to URLs, anything else is dealt with inside the *Service* classes).
Here is a simplified version of my controller

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class Controller<Entity, Id, BrowseResponse, ShowResponse, Request,
    Repository extends com.example.repositories.Repository<Entity, Id>,
    Service extends com.example.services.Service<Entity, Id, BrowseResponse, ShowResponse, Request, Repository>> {

    protected final Service service;

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<BrowseResponse> index() {
        return service.index();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void create(@Valid @RequestBody Request request) {
        service.create(request);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ShowResponse show(@PathVariable Id id) {
        return service.show(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public void update(@Valid @RequestBody Request request, @PathVariable Id id) {
        service.update(request, id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Id id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }
}
```

With this approach I can create a concrete Controller with less code like the following

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/items")
public class ItemController extends Controller<Item, Long, ItemBrowseResponse, ItemShowResponse, ItemRequest, ItemRepository, ItemService> {
    public ItemController(ItemService service) {
        super(service);
    }
```

Cool now I have all methods mapped correctly with out having to write them all.
my problem is that I have a single use case where I need to get a `RequestParam` in my *index* function. Example: get the param *page* if I'm using *Pagination*

So now if I redefine `index` function like this

```java
@GetMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<LevelResponse> index(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page) {
    return service.index(page);
}
```

I get an error creating the bean

> There is already 'itemController' bean method

I tried overriding the default function like this

```java
@Deprecated
@Override
public List<LevelResponse> index() {
    return super.index();
}
```

Yet the error still exists.

How can I remove the mapping from the inherited method?

*Note*: NOT using the the generic *Controller* is not recommanded as re-implementing all methods would be a nightmare

Comment: Looks like you should rethink the inheretance. Maybe you need a `GenericConcontroller`, which do not have the index method and extend a `GenericControllerWithIndex` wich implements this method. Amd than extend the concrete Controller from this one you need

Comment: BTW: `@Deprecated` and `@Override` are only compile time annotations and do nothing at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the answer by @ursa, I can use *RequestMapping Overloading* as a work around.

As the RequestMapping enbales the creation of multiple functions to deal with the different RequestParams. I was able to redefine the original `index` function to only deal with a placeholder param as follows

```java
    @Deprecated
    @GetMapping(params = {"deprecated"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public List<ItemResponse> index() {
        return super.index();
    }
```

In this way I can use the default mapping as I need

```java
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<ItemResponse> index(...params) {
        return service.index(departmentId);
    }
```

It does not remove the old implementation completely but it constraints it to the use of the param `deprecated` which can actually be useful

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `params` attribute to `@GetMapping` annotation in overloaded method:

```
@GetMapping(params = {"page"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<LevelResponse> index(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page) {
    return service.index(page);
}
```

See similar question: [Overload Controller Method in Java Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30380498/2078908)

Comment: In my use case I need the new index function as the base mapping, but this inspired me a good workaround